# Can't share WD MyBook on network

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, network-shares, mybook

Trying to share part of a MyBook *(WD10000h1cs w/last release firmware)* on the network is unsuccessful. Connected to an XP Pro pc, I try to access it through a Win7 pc. The drive shows up, but when clicking on it, after a while of waiting it says

> \'drive name' is not accessible. You might not have permission.....
>   Not enough server storage is available to process this command.

Btw I share other folders from that pc without problems, only the MyBook shares fail. Any ideas?